# Ruby .reject after .split behaves weirdly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order to split a string on `,` or `;` I use this simple code

```
string.split(/[\s,;]/).reject!(&:empty?)
```

It works well for strings such as these

```
"entry1, entry2, entry3"
"entry1"
"entry1, entry2,"
```

but the problem is with `"entry1,"` (single element followed by a comma)

Please have a look at these examples

```
2.2.4 :033 > 'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/).reject!(&:empty?)
 => nil
2.2.4 :034 > 'entry1, entry2'.split(/[\s,;]/).reject!(&:empty?)
 => ["entry1", "entry2"]
2.2.4 :035 > 'entry1, entry2,'.split(/[\s,;]/).reject!(&:empty?)
 => ["entry1", "entry2"]
```

So

```
2.2.4 :033 > 'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/).reject!(&:empty?)
 => nil
```

but

```
2.2.4 :037 > 'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/)
 => ["entry1"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look into [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) of `reject!` method:

> Equivalent to #delete_if, deleting elements from self for which the block evaluates to true, but returns nil if no changes were made.

Since `'entry1, entry2'.split(/[\s,;]/)` evaluates to `["entry1", "", "entry2"]`, i. e. there's an empty string. That means that there is job to be done.

But `'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/)` evaluates to `["entry1"]`, so `nil` is returned, since no changes were made.

In order to make it more predictable, I'd suggest either using `reject` method:

```
'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["entry1"]
```

Or rely on the variable mutated by `reject!`:

```
a = 'entry1,'.split(/[\s,;]/)
a.reject(&:empty?)
a # => ["entry1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are adding reject to remove empty values from your split, you can change it for something like this, to remove this need:

```
irb(main):016:0> string = "entry1, entry2; sadq;as"
=> "entry1, entry2; sadq;as"
irb(main):017:0> string.split(/\s*,\s*|\s*;\s*/)
=> ["entry1", "entry2", "sadq", "as"]
```

or this is another option, using map to remove the empty spaces

```
irb(main):016:0> string = "entry1, entry2; sadq;as"
=> "entry1, entry2; sadq;as"
irb(main):020:0> string.split(/,|;/).map(&:strip)
=> ["entry1", "entry2", "sadq", "as"]
```

it doesn't answer your questions, but can help you to have simpler code there